# Platform.getBundle returns null

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have an eclipse plugin and have learned that I can retrieve a workspace-dependent bundle path for that like this:

```
Bundle bundle = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(getClass());
IPath path = Platform.getStateLocation(bundle);
```

If I put that code into the start-method of my Bundle activator class everything works fine. But I would need the path in another class within my plugin.

Now, I tried to do get the 'Bundle' like this:

```
    bundleID = "de.some.thing.plugin" // ID of that plugin like in plugin.xml
    Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle(bundleID);
    ...
```

But this returns null. Can anybody help me troubleshooting or understanding why it does not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't say what `bundleId` is. This must be a string containing the plugin id - this is the value of the `Bundle-SymbolicName` in the plugin's MANIFEST.MF (leaving out anything after any semicolon).

In the MANIFEST.MF editor this is shown in the 'ID' field on the 'Overview' tab.

Note: `FrameworkUtil.getBundle(getClass())` will work in any class in your plugin not just the Activator.

Comment: I did not expect that FrameworkUtil.getBundle(getClass()) would work in any class of my plugin. But you are right. That helps! Thanks a lot!